# Airflow Task Failure Slack notifcations

Tags: python, airflow

I am working to integrate task failure slack notifications for Airflow.  Based on other questions asked on SO regarding this topic I have the below code executing on my Airflow node.  It works as intended (one task fails one succeeds) with the notable exception of I dont get the slack notification for the failed task.  I have verified my ability to post slack messages from Airflow with more generic code that does not reference an event to trigger off of.  Any help with why this does not work would be appreciated.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.timezone import datetime
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook


def fail():
    raise Exception("Task failed intentionally for testing purpose")

def success():
    print("success")

SLACK_CONN_ID = 'slack_connection'

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID)
    slack_msg = """
            :red_circle: Task Failed. 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url} 
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
        )
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_test',
        http_conn_id='slack_connection',
        webhook_token=slack_webhook_token,
        message=slack_msg,
        username='airflow')
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airlfow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 6),
    'retries': 0,
    'on_failure_callback':task_fail_slack_alert
}

with DAG(
        'slacktest3',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='slacktest',
        catchup=False,


) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test",
        python_callable=fail
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test2",
        python_callable=success
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

updated function and now alerting works. Still not sure why orignal code does not.  Updated code below for reference...

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.timezone import datetime
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook



def fail():
    raise Exception("Task failed intentionally for testing purpose")

def success():
    print("success")

def slack_notification(context):
    slack_msg = """
            :red_circle: Task Failed. 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url} 
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
        )
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_notification',
        http_conn_id='slack_connection',
        message=slack_msg)
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airlfow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 6),
    'retries': 0,
    'on_failure_callback':slack_notification()
}

with DAG(
        'slacktest3',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='slacktest',
        catchup=False,


) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test",
        python_callable=fail
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="slack_notification_test2",
        python_callable=success
    )
```